# Python | Cómo quitar espacio entre la variable fruit y la "s"

Tags: python

¿Cómo se quita el espacio entre la variable fruit y le letra "s"?

```
fruit="manzana"
print(fruit,"s")
```

saca en pantalla: "manzana s"
¿Cómo se hace para que saque "manzanas"?

¿Hay que sumar en estos casos?

```
 fruit="manzana"
 print(fruit+"s")
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Solo tenias que probarlo y veras que el segundo caso no hay espacio.

Comment: Es correcto al utilizar el operador "+" en cadenas las puedes lograr unir. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print()` toma uno o varios objetos y los imprime en pantalla delimitados por una coma
En tu caso tu variable `fruit` es un objeto y la cadena 's' es otro objeto, por lo que te va a separar esos casos, no es una cadena completa. Tu ya diste la solución, debes concatenar para que salga en una sola línea y no pasar distintos objetos a la función. Eso lo puedes ver si escribes

```
print( fruit, 's', sep='||' )
```

En este caso el separador ya no será una coma, si no un doble pipe

Te dejo la [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp) para que experimentes con ello

Answer (score 1):

Al utilizar el operar + con dos Strings lo que hace es concatenar los strings, al igual que si usas un string y un int o number.
Así que la segunda forma que usaste es correcta:

```
fruit="manzana"
 print(fruit+"s")
```